# Equivalent of auto layout in GTK#

Tags: autolayout, gtk, gtk#

I pretty new to GTK# and come from mostly iOS/Mac development background with Xcode. Xcode's interface builder provides [auto layout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html), which resizes and positions the UI elements according the device's screen resolution/size and the constraints given by developer. However, I can't find such a tool with GTK#. The closest elements I was to find were HBox, VBox, Table etc. Is there an equivalent tool for auto layout in GTK#? I am using Xamarin Studio if that changes anything.

Comment: There is no Auto Layout clone in GTK+. If someone has built such a thing, it would be a third party library; I am not aware of any. Boxes and grids are how to do layout in GTK+, yes. Read the GTK+ tutorial and the documentation for GtkBox and GtkGrid and the GtkBox vs GtkGrid pages on [the main GTK+ documentation page](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/) to learn how to use them. (You'll find that GtkBox is similar to NSStackView.)

Comment: Also I'd caution against trying to clone Auto Layout using boxes and grids (you can try if you want, but I'm making no guarantees of success). If I were to try recreating the constraint system with GTK+, I'd do it by creating a custom GtkContainer subclass for it instead, which is rather advanced. (I currently am trying to do the opposite: clone the two with Auto Layout; that's easier, but still problematic.)

Comment: @andlabs Thanks for the advice, I will take a look to what you said.

Comment: You have a specific Gtk# tutorial here: http://zetcode.com/gui/gtksharp/